# How to use preg_replace to remove excessive single spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

We are extracting text from PDF files, and there is a high frequency of results that contain malformed text.  Specifically adding spaces between the characters of a word.  e.g.  `SEATTLE` is being returned as `S E A T T L E`.

Is there a RegEx expression for preg_replace that can remove any spaces in the case of `n` number of single character "words"?  Specifically, remove spaces from any occurrence of a string that is more than 3 single alpha characters and is separated by spaces?

If googled this for awhile, but can't even *imagine* how to construct the expression.  As expressed in a comment, I don't want ALL spaces removed, but only when there is an occurrence of >3 single alpha characters, e.g. `Welcome to the Greater S E A T T L E area` should become `Welcome to the Greater SEATTLE area`.  The result is to be used in full text searching, so case sensitivity is not a concern.

Comment: You should use a simple approach with a `preg_replace_callback`. Match `'~\b[A-Za-z](?: [A-Za-z]){2,}\b~'` and `str_replace` spaces in the anonymous function.

Comment: This looks promising, but as you may be able to tell, RegEx is Sorcery to me.  Can you provide that expression in a working example as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a simple approach with a `preg_replace_callback`. Match `'~\b[A-Za-z](?: [A-Za-z]){2,}\b~'` and `str_replace` spaces in the anonymous function:

```
$regex = '~\b[A-Za-z](?: [A-Za-z]){2,}\b~';
$result = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($m) {
     return str_replace(" ", "", $m[0]);
}, $s);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vx6UZL/1).

To only match sequences of uppercase letters, remove `a-z` from the pattern:

```
$regex = '~\b[A-Z](?: [A-Z]){2,}\b~';
```

And another thing: there may be soft/hard spaces, tabs, other kind of whitespace. Then, use

```
$regex = '~\b[A-Za-z](?:\h[A-Za-z]){2,}\b~u';
                        ^^                ^
```

Finally, to match any Unicode letter, use `\p{L}` (to only match uppercase ones, `\p{Lu}`) instead of `[a-zA-Z]`:

```
$regex = '~\b\p{L}(?:\h\p{L}){2,}\b~u';
```

#### **NOTE**: It will most probably fail to work in some cases, e.g. when there are one-letter words. You will have to handle those cases separately/manually. Anyway, there is no safe regex-only way to fix OCR issues.

**Pattern details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[A-Za-z]` - a single letter
- `(?: [A-Za-z]){2,}` - 2 or more occurrences of

  - - a space (`\h` matches any kind of horizontal whitespace)
  - `[A-Za-z]` - a single letter
- `\b` - a word boundary

When usign `u` modifier, `\h` becomes Unicode-aware.

Comment: THANK you...I did get your comment working after I removed the ~ on Regtest101.com.  Will this replace all occurrences? RegTester stops at the first occurrence.

Comment: I happen to be waiting for a long CLI script that's running with my debuggger, so was doing this reserach in the meantime.

Comment: @GDP As you see, all other answers use much more complicated regexps. That is what I meant when saying "a simple approach". I also thought about `\G` based regex, but when you have the whole PHP language power at hand, this approach is the best, IMHO, since the pattern is very readable and easy to enhance if you need to avoid specific contexts.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in one go:

```
(?i:(?<!\S)([a-z]) +((?1))|\G(?!\A) +((?1))\b)
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/wTBWU6/1)

Explanation:

```
(?i: # Start of non-capturing group with case-insensitive modifier on
    (?<!\S) # Negative lookbehind to ensure there is no leading non-whitespace character
    ([a-z]) + # Capture one letter and at least one space
    ((?1)) # Capture one letter in 2nd capturing group
    | # Or
    \G(?!\A) + # Start match from where previous match ends 
               # with matching spaces
    ((?1))\b # Match a letter at word boundary
) # End of non-capturing group
```

PHP code:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(?i:(?<!\S)([a-z]) +((?1))|\G(?!\A) +((?1))\b)~', '$1$2$3', $str);
```

Comment: This seems to work as well, but I have to accept the other answer as he answered first, got me started in the right direction to begin with, but THANK you!

Answer (score 1):

You may use this pure regex approach with lookarounds and `\G`:

```
$re = '~\b(?:(?=(?:\pL\h+){3}\pL\b)|(?<!^)\G)(\pL)\h+(?=\pL\b)~';

$repl = preg_replace($re, '$1', $str);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pSalnJ/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Match word boundary
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(?=(?:\pL\h+){3}\pL\b)`: Lookahead to assert we have 3+ single letters separated by 1+ spaces
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?<!^)\G`: `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match.  `(?<!^)` ensures we don't match start of the string for the first match
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `(\pL)`: Match a single letter and capture it
- `\h+`: Followed by 1+ horizontal whitespace
- `(?=\pL\b)`: Assert that we only have a single letter ahead
- In the **replacement** we use `$1` which is the letter left of whitespace we capture

Comment: This seems to work as well, but I have to accept the other answer as he answered first, got me started in the right direction to begin with, but THANK you!